# remove() function doesn't work as expected

Tags: c

I am working with a code that generates a fixed number of files and keeps that number. After every new file is created, an old one has to be deleted. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // needed for malloc
#include <string.h> // needed for strcpy
#include <unistd.h>

#define Extension ".txt"
#define LOG_MIN_FILENAME_SIZE 32
#define NBR_OF_FILES 6

char buffer[LOG_MIN_FILENAME_SIZE];

int timez = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int count = 0;

FILE* pf = NULL;
char* ListOfFiles[6];

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ListOfFiles[i] = calloc(LOG_MIN_FILENAME_SIZE + 1, 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d" "%d" Extension, minutes, timez);

        if (access(buffer, F_OK) == -1) {
            pf = fopen(buffer, "w"); // create the file
            count++;
            fclose(pf); //closing the files is necessary
            if (count >= NBR_OF_FILES) {
                remove(ListOfFiles[0]); //remove the oldes file.
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < NBR_OF_FILES - 1; i++) {
                strcpy(ListOfFiles[i], ListOfFiles[i + 1]); // u cant use just normal assignment because it copies the head ot the pointer rather than the actual content of it
            }

            strcpy(ListOfFiles[NBR_OF_FILES - 1], buffer);
        }
        timez++;
        minutes++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NBR_OF_FILES - 1; i++) {
        printf("%s", ListOfFiles[i]);
    }
}
```

In the output, I get only one file created at a time (with every execution). When I execute the program more than `NBR_OF_FILE` times, no files are deleted! Do you have any idea that what the issue could be?

Comment: You have 6 files, but the `for` with `calloc` only runs 3 times.

Comment: Not sure why, but it happens.

Comment: @anastaciu your comment is the best Thing  ><D . thnx . ist now removed :D